# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.JMSContext on tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, classnotfoundexception

I have a spring web application which I am trying to deploy on tomcat 7. I got following error on tomcat 7 start-up:

Caused by:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.JMSContext

This is because tomcat could not find `javaee-api-7.0.jar` which is present in my application's `WEB-INF/lib` folder. However, if I copy this to `tomcat/lib`, error is fixed and tomcat can load the class.

But I don't want to copy any additional jars to tomcat/lib. Can someone help here so that tomcat can find above jar in application's lib. Am I missing any classpath handler entries? I have not added any explicitly.

Answer (score 44):

I was also facing the same issue when I moved from spring-3.0 to spring-5.0 while using Tomcat-7 to deploy my application. I added below maven dependency in **pom.xml** file and it got resolved.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The root cause I found is, **UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter** class provided by **spring-jms-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar** was using **JMSContext** class internally. This class was not available in **jms-1.1.jar** which I was using with **spring-jms-3.2.4.jar**.

So I replaced **jms-1.1.jar** with **javax.jms-api-2.0.1.jar**

I would suggest you to add/upgrade your jms jar as mentioned above according to you spring version.
Hope this works!

Comment: In `spring-jms` the `javax-jms ` dependency is marked `provided` and hence needs to be added by the container.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in an **Apache karaf 4.2.7** environment over JDK 11.0.2, in my case the exception prints

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: **javax.jms.JMSContext not found** by org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-jms_1.1_spec

It works by installing:
**bundle:install mvn:javax.jms/javax.jms-api/2.0.1**